# Why isn't my for loop working for my expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I want this function to read a password, and check to see if it has at least 1 number in it. If not, it needs to return False. I need to use a for loop with the range function and this is what I have:

```
def hasNum(password):
for i in range(0,len(password),1):
    if password == str('0123456789'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I've tried different variations and it's driving me crazy. Can someone possibly explain to a rookie what they're doing wrong?

Comment: I've been looking into using the [] operator, but I can't seem to get it work using that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop tests *once* if the password is `0123456789`; if it matches that string, `True` is returned, otherwise `False` is returned outright. The `range(0, len(password), 1)` is a complicated way to write `range(len(password))`; likewise `str('0123456789')` is a complicated way of writing `'0123456789'`.

What you need is to iterate over each character, and if it is a digit, then return `True`; if none is, then return `False`:

```
def has_digit(password):
    for character in password:
        if character.isdigit():
            return True

    return False
```

The final `return False` is *outside* the loop - we must check each and every character in the password before returning `False`.

This can be simplified with `any`:

```
def has_digit(password):
    return any(ch.isdigit() for ch in password)
```

Comment: Gah bet me to it, deleted mine, yours covers it all.

Comment: I think actually the 'I'll write your code for you' kind of answer on a question that could probably be significantly improved (i.e. it's unlikely it will ever help anyone else in its current for) is actually a really bad idea. Makes the site worse.

Comment: @pvg you should answer some [tag:c] questions :D

Comment: @Antti That actually helps me a lot. I feel so stupid for over complicating this. I tend to do that when I spend a long time thinking about something. Thank you so much.